# Is there a Microsoft Excel automated (or interactive) "VLOOKUP" program or SaaS where I can combine 2 excel sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office

I have 2 sheets and I know to use **VLOOKUP** to cross-reference the sheets and join the data into one sheet.

I am wondering if there is an application for windows, or an online SaaS that allows you to input two excel sheets and it will do the equivalent of VLOOKUP to combine the data into one sheet.

For reference, I am using MS Office 2007. Maybe the newer versions have a wizard-like method of doing VLOOKUP?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data you are working with?  Is the data in the two sheets similar (same data points, same formatting/order, etc)

Comment: @James the data is similar. Name, phone, address. However one list is newer than the other and has less entries (20K vs 30K) and I need to pull in the remaining entries from the bigger list without removing the updated entries in the newer list.

Comment: So to clarify, Data Set (DS) A is smaller and newer and contains some of the same data as DS-B which is older but has more entries.  So keep all of DS-A and copy only the entries in DS-B that do not appear in DS-A (as DS-A is newer data)

Comment: @James yes correct